# Do we have any REST API for sonar qube to get the project details by project name or key?

Tags: sonarqube

Do we have any REST API for sonar qube to get the project details by project name or key?

I don't see one in the list of services provided in sonar qube wiki.

https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/projects

Comment: what is the version of SonarQube? A Web API exists with many WS. You can call api/components/show, api/components/search depending on your need. More generally, you can look at the Web API documentation at the bottom of any page

Answer (score -2):

Finally found the below url through some web search

http://localhost:9000/api/projects/index?search=sonarProjectName